# Eclipse - Java project's .bin ignored in running plug-in

Tags: eclipse-plugin, text-editor, buildpath, eclipse-jdt

My project can't seem to find the compiled java classes in the `bin` folder, although they are all there. This affects the basic editor functionalities, like code completion and code navigation etc.

I have several folders containing `.java` files and add them as sources through `"Use as Source Folder"` to the project source. They are compiled and added to the project's `bin` folder. If I go to the menu `Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Source` tab, all the source folders that were added appear and the default output folder is set to `MyProject/bin` so I don't see where the problem lies...

I managed to get it working by adding the `bin` folder through `"Add External Class Folder"` to the Libraries and then giving `MyProject` as `"Source Attachment"` (for the navigation).

This is more than ugly so I was wondering where the problem could lie...

Comment: Check the `.classpath` file in your project. Is there `<classpathentry ... />` tag of added folder?

Comment: yes, there is one... `<classpathentry kind="src" path="MyFolder"/>`

Comment: Only one? Is `MyFolder` you added by `Use as Source Folder`?

Comment: There are more of them, but all are present in the `.classpath`. And all of them were added through `Use as Source Folder`. Can it have something to do with the project running in a plug-in? The workspace is created at runtime, being `runtime-EclipseApplication`. It is only speculation...